# Is it possible to open a handle to the Windows Defender (MsMpEng.exe) process with PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS or PROCESS_TERMINATE rights?

Tags: c, winapi, ntdll

I have followed Microsoft's on [How to obtain a handle to any process with SeDebugPrivilege](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/131065/how-to-obtain-a-handle-to-any-process-with-sedebugprivilege)
to gain the `SE_DEBUG` privilege in my process token.

However, when trying to open a handle to `MsMpEng.exe` with full rights, I receive an error code of `c0000022` (`STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED`).

I am wondering if I have made a mistake, or if it is simply not possible to gain that level of access rights to the process.

My code for opening the handle to the Defender process is below. This block follows the block for adding the `SE_DEBUG` privilege to my token.

```
if (Process32First(hSnap, &pt))
{
    do {
        if (!strcmp(pt.szExeFile, "MsMpEng.exe"))
        {
            printf("%d\n", pt.th32ProcessID);
            OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES oa = { sizeof(oa), 0, 0, 0, 0 };
            CLIENT_ID pid = { (HANDLE)pt.th32ProcessID, NULL };
            NTSTATUS status = NtOpenProcess(&hDef, PROCESS_TERMINATE, &oa, &pid);
            if (status == STATUS_SUCCESS)
            {
                printf("Handle to defender opened!");
                NtClose(hDef);
            }
            else
                printf("%x", status);
        }

    } while (Process32Next(hSnap, &pt));
}
```

Comment: driver can control process open handles with [`ObRegisterCallbacks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-obregistercallbacks)  and denny open some process handles. this is for example. as result not always possible open some process

Comment: MsMpEng.exe is a protected process (PsProtectedSignerAntimalware-Light), so SeDebugPrivilege will not allow terminate access. Note that this protection breaks the implementation of the maximum-allowed access bit. The process manager lets us open the process with query-limited information (0x1000) and, if the debug privilege is enabled, suspend-resume (0x800) and set-limited information (0x2000) access. But requesting maximum-allowed access is denied.